# how to provide grant to specific user role automatically for frequently drop and create table

Tags: sql, oracle

I Have 2 schema in my database. One of the schema has a package which is using a another schema's table. The Table from another schema, which is frequently drop and create with same name after a time span.

So, when the table has drop at the same moment the package from another schema will be invalid due the table.

Is there any way to provide a grant access will remain as it is after the table drop or any way to recompile automatically that package. Please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is that table being dropped and created by a script or manually? You could add the grant command in the table creation script.

Comment: by a script that table being dropped and created.

Comment: Assuming that it really makes sense to drop and recreate the table (which seems fishy to start with), why wouldn't the script include restoring the grants?  Oracle will automatically recompile the package when it is next executed but you could do that in the script as well.

Comment: could you please provide an example of the script, which will auto compile the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't any automatic task to do this. you should write code to automate this. please check http://psoug.org/reference/ddl_trigger.html. it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Packages will always become invalid if one of their dependant objects is dropped. Recompiling the package while the table does not exist will not work, the package will still be be invalid.

Consider deleting all rows from the table (or truncating it) instead of dropping and recreating it.

Otherwise, try to minimise the time between dropping and recreating the table. Make sure all relevant grants and synonyms are created at the same time as the table.

The only workaround I can think of is to create a copy of the table before you drop it. If you use a synonym to reference the table in the package, you could "trick" the package into using this copy of the table while you drop the actual one. The package would still become invalid while you change the synonym, but this would only be for a short amount of time.

The only ideal solution to this problem is to stop dropping the table.